# Need help in Excel macro for merged cells

Tags: vba

I am Preparing a CSV from Excel. There are few merged cells in excel. Need to make the excel ready for converting to csv file. so need to  Un merge excel cells and fill those columns headers repetitive for all cells.Need a MAcro in VBA to achive this

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.MergeCells = False** look at this example below:

```
Sub merge_Bouton1_Clic()
    With Range("A1:C1")
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("B1:C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
    
End Sub
```

**[RESULT]:**

[image]